# How to verify if Google Firebase admin SDK credentials are correct

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-authentication

Is there any way to verify if Firebase Admin SDK Credentials is correct when initializing app with below code?

```
ctx := context.Background()
opt := option.WithCredentialsFile("path/to/firebase-admin-sdk-cred.json")
app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, nil, opt)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Because I seem to not get any error when I tried to intentionally put the wrong credentials. I check the implementation of the **firebase.NewApp()** but it seems it only throw error when there is no config. Below is the code of **firebase.NewApp()**

```
func NewApp(ctx context.Context, config *Config, opts ...option.ClientOption) (*App, error) {
o := []option.ClientOption{option.WithScopes(internal.FirebaseScopes...)}
o = append(o, opts...)
if config == nil {
    var err error
    if config, err = getConfigDefaults(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
}

pid := getProjectID(ctx, config, o...)
ao := defaultAuthOverrides
if config.AuthOverride != nil {
    ao = *config.AuthOverride
}

return &App{
    authOverride:     ao,
    dbURL:            config.DatabaseURL,
    projectID:        pid,
    serviceAccountID: config.ServiceAccountID,
    storageBucket:    config.StorageBucket,
    opts:             o,
}, nil 
}
```

so Is there any way to check if the credentials is valid during the initialization of Firebase Admin(app) instance because it seems catching error isn't the solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `google.golang.org/api/transport` to force the validation and fail fast

```
// Check if credential is correct
_, err = transport.Creds(ctx, opt)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is in the documentation:

> Some use cases require you to create multiple apps at the same time.
> For example, you might want to read data from the Realtime Database of
> one Firebase project and mint custom tokens for another project. Or
> you might want to authenticate two apps with separate credentials. The
> Firebase SDK allows you create multiple apps at the same time, each
> with their own configuration information.

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

I assume the only way to check credentials is invoke an `Auth` method for example:

```
client, err := app.Auth(context.Background())
```

Comment: I've tried that and it still doesn't throw me an error. However it throws error only if the private_key is invalid, otherwise it still give me no error.